# Working with series (A-Level Further Maths), a bracket was expanded and the result makes no sense to me

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

(This is just a small part of the question):

$\frac13n(n+1) + n$ turns into $9n + 9 + 6$ and I have no clue as to how,
maybe I am missing something very obvious but I just don't see it.

Please help.

If it helps here is that entire line:

$\frac16n(n+1)(2n+1) + 3(\frac12)n(n+1) + n$,  which then turns into (according to the answers):

$\frac16n(2n^2 + 3n + 1 + 9n + 9 + 6)$

Comment: the expression has been factorised, using $\frac16n$ as the common factor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to factor out $\frac16n$ from all of the terms.  To do this, replace $1/2$ by $3\times (1/6)$ in the second term, and $1$ by $6\times (1/6)$ in the last term:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{6} n (n+1) &(2n+1) + 3 \frac{1}{2} n (n+1) + n \\ &= \frac{1}{6} n (n+1) (2n+1) + 3 \left[ 3 \cdot \frac{1}{6} \right] n (n+1) + \left[ 6 \cdot \frac{1}{6} \right] n
\end{align*}
Now pull out a common factor of $\frac{1}{6} n$ from each of the terms.  You should then get the desired result.